# T-test in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, hypothesis-test

If I want to calculate the mean of two categories in Pandas, I can do it like this:

```
data = {'Category': ['cat2','cat1','cat2','cat1','cat2','cat1','cat2','cat1','cat1','cat1','cat2'],
        'values': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,5,1]}
my_data = DataFrame(data)
my_data.groupby('Category').mean()

Category:     values:   
cat1     2.666667
cat2     1.600000
```

I have a lot of data formatted this way, and now I need to do a *T*-test to see if the mean of *cat1* and *cat2* are statistically different. How can I do that?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

it depends what sort of t-test you want to do (one sided or two sided dependent or independent) but it should be as simple as:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

cat1 = my_data[my_data['Category']=='cat1']
cat2 = my_data[my_data['Category']=='cat2']

ttest_ind(cat1['values'], cat2['values'])
>>> (1.4927289925706944, 0.16970867501294376)
```

it returns a tuple with the t-statistic & the p-value

see here for other t-tests http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Answer (score 19):

EDIT: I had not realized this was about the data format. You [could use](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-series-or-dicts)

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
two_data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data['Category'])
```

Then [accessing the categories](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection) is as simple as

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(two_data.loc['cat'], two_data.loc['cat2'], equal_var=False)
```

The [`loc operator`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection) accesses rows by label.

---

As [@G Garcia said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413842/1587329)

> one sided or two sided dependent or independent

If you have **two independent samples** but you *do not know that they have equal variance*, you can use [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). It is as simple as

```
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(cat1['values'], cat2['values'], equal_var=False)
```

For reasons to prefer Welch's test, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305/when-conducting-a-t-test-why-would-one-prefer-to-assume-or-test-for-equal-vari.

For **two dependent samples**, you can use

```
scipy.stats.ttest_rel(cat1['values'], cat2['values'])
```

Answer (score 8):

I simplify the code a little bit.

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
ttest_ind(*my_data.groupby('Category')['value'].apply(lambda x:x.values))
```

Comment: instead of "list(x)" you can also use x.values, which is 2x faster :)

Comment: Cool, I edit the answer as you said, Thanks!