# pandas dataframe: subset by column + groupby another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas dataframes and would appreciate help with the following problem (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13404468/2323484)). I have the following data:

```
data = {'Cat1': [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2],
        'Cat2': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        'values': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,5,1]}
my_data = DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to perform a `ttest_ind` for every category in `Cat2` to distinguish between categories in `Cat1`.

The way I see it, I could separate the data into

```
cat1_1 = my_data[my_data['Cat1']==1]
cat1_2 = my_data[my_data['Cat1']==2]
```

And then loop through every value in `Cat2` to perform a t-test:

```
for cat2 in [0,1]:

    subset_1 = cat1_1[cat1_1['Cat2']==cat2]
    subset_2 = cat1_2[cat1_2['Cat2']==cat2]

    t, p = ttest_ind(subset_1['values'], subset_2['values'])
```

But this seems really convoluted. Could there be a simpler solution, maybe with `groupby`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can try merge on two dfs

Comment: @galaxyan Could you please elaborate what you mean by that? Thanks!

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html it may help.

Comment: But I already have a single dataframe. I think I'm looking for ways to split the data nicely, not merge, right? But I'd be happy to hear the solution you have in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `Cat2` and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `f`:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

data = {'Cat1': [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2],
        'Cat2': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        'values': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,5,1]}
my_data =pd.DataFrame(data)
print my_data
    Cat1  Cat2  values
0      2     0       1
1      1     0       2
2      2     0       3
3      1     0       1
4      2     0       2
5      1     0       3
6      2     1       1
7      1     1       2
8      1     1       3
9      1     1       5
10     2     1       1

def f(x):
    #print x   
    cat1_1 = x[x['Cat1']==1]
    cat1_2 = x[x['Cat1']==2]

    t, p = ttest_ind(cat1_1['values'], cat1_2['values'])
    return pd.Series({'a':t, 'b':p})     

print my_data.groupby('Cat2').apply(f) 
            a         b
Cat2                   
0     0.00000  1.000000
1     2.04939  0.132842
```