# How to run t-tests with groupby in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.append(['A'] * 50, [['B'] * 50, ['C'] * 50]),
                      'value': np.random.randn(3 * 50)})
```

I would like to run run a `t-test` between all groups `A`, `B`, `C`.

Is there a pythonic way to do that ? I need something more generic than manually slicing the df

Comment: Possible dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413842/4985099 (look at the last solution looks similar to above problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-test in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404468/t-test-in-pandas)

Comment: If you want to test all groups with the same test, you might want to consider an ANOVA instead of multiple t-tests

Comment: I need something more generic than manually slicing the df

Comment: @drops if the mean of group `A` does not differ significantly from the mean of group `B`, but it differs significantly from the mean of group `C`, then ANOVA will reject the null, but you will not know "where this rejection comes from", right ?

Comment: @quant If your ANOVA leads to a rejection of the Null hypothesis, you can do a Tukey post-hoc test to see where the differences come from

Comment: @drops I wasnt aware of this one. after quickly skimming through online, it seems to do the same thing as multiple t-tests. are there any big differences between multiple t-tests and the Tukey post-hoc test, according to your knowledge ?

Comment: @quant if you do multiple tests instead of only one, you increase the chances of getting false positives, i.e. getting a p-value below your threshold by chance. You can also circumvent the increased probability of false positives by dividing your threshold, for example 0.05, by the number of tests you do. Then your new threshold to reject the null hypothesis is 0.05/3 = 0.0167 (also called Bonferroni correction)

Comment: @drops Maybe this is turned into a stats course, but why would this be the case ? I mean why is the chance of getting more FP increased ?

Comment: @quant An exaplantion would go beyond the limits of a comment. I recommend starting here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `itertools.combinations` here to get the combinations of the unique values in `group`:

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

grps = test_df['group'].unique()
combs = combinations(grps, 2)

ttests = {
    f'{c1}_{c2}': ttest_ind(
        test_df.loc[test_df['group'] == c1, 'value'], 
        test_df.loc[test_df['group'] == c2, 'value']
    ) for c1, c2 in combs
}
```

**Output**

```
{'A_B': Ttest_indResult(statistic=1.2288295532881655, pvalue=0.22207832845954317),
 'A_C': Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.18451518261887467, pvalue=0.8539906100478168),
 'B_C': Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.8658034013302348, pvalue=0.3887126452109223)}
```