# Why does t-test return nan/pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, t-test

df:

```
gender   order
F         1
F         1
M         1
F         1
M         1
F         1
```

**Aim**: To check if the mean of F and M are significantly different. I want to check if there is a significant difference between females and males for order 1. (I feel there is something wrong but I cannot figure it out at this stage). My code gives `Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)` as a result; I used this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404468/t-test-in-pandas) to the below code:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
cat1 = df[df['gender']=='F']
cat2 = df[df['gender']=='M']
t_tst_rsult = ttest_ind(cat1['order'], cat2['order'])
print(t_tst_rsult)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `cat1['order']` and `cat2['order']`? Are they indeed floating point Series?

Comment: the 2 groups (`M` and `F`) have identical values, so no difference will be detected by the test, hence the nan pvalues

Comment: As Simon said +1, change the values in your order column and re-run the same code and you'll see proper results

Comment: All the records in order have value=1. Do you think t-test is a proper solution to see the difference?

Comment: well because the values are identical, there is literally no difference to be seen

Comment: if everything in `order` is 1, there's no standard deviation, or variation, there's no purpose in doing any test whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

A better test for this sample is [One Sample Test of Proportions](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/SAS/SAS6-CategoricalData/SAS6-CategoricalData2.html) in case someone has the same issue.