Way to iteratively conduct t tests to determine significant difference in Pandas (Python)?
Looking for some direction here. I've got survey data for two separate administration years. 2020 and 2024. I'm tasked with identifying any significant differences in the results. The issue is there are over 40 questions. I have the survey data in an excel spreadsheet with the column headers as the question variables and the response values in the rows.
Fortunately the question variables are the same between the two administration periods.
I was considering joining the two datasets and adding a column to determine the 2020 administration and the 2024 administration. From there, is there maybe a python package or some way to iterate through t-tests for each of the question variables? Just looking for the quickest way to do this that doesn't included individual t-tests for each question.
In other words, if I have my table structured like the below, and I want to run t tests for each question (Quest1, Quest2, Quest3), is there a way to iteratively do this via Python?



SurveyAdminYear
Quest1
Quest2
Quest3




2020
3
4
2


2020
5
1
3


2024
2
2
3


2024
1
4
1




Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404468/t-test-in-pandas answer your question?
